# ListView Selection Timer

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I use the following method to select all the items in a ListView:

```
private void listView_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.Items)
            item.Selected = true;

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

When I click an already selected item and then press Ctrl+A, it selects all the items but after 1 second selection goes back to the single item that was clicked.

**Solution**

I couldn't find where ListView starts a timer or changes the selection, simply ignoring WM_TIMER doesn't stop the timer, so we have to restore the selection manually:

```
public class CustomListView : ListView
{
    private const int WM_TIMER = 0x113;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg != WM_TIMER)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
        else
        {
            var selectionCache = Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(x => x.Selected).ToArray();

            BeginUpdate();

            base.WndProc(ref m);

            for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
                Items[i].Selected = selectionCache[i];

            EndUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about if you don't hold down Ctrl and just press A?

Comment: Yes, I thought that it could be the reason, but nothing happens if i press A with no modifier key.

Comment: A fast solution i've just found is ignoring WM_TIMER in WndProc

Comment: I've seen this complaint before, I have yet to repro it.  Document your version of Windows and the View property you selected.  A snippet from your Designer.cs file is best.

Comment: I'm running Windows XP. The View property is set to Details, all the others are default.